# Events Log source

Tags: eventviewer

I am doing a critical review of some software which gathers information about activities on a system.

some of the information that is displayed to user is available in the events viewer. This is all good for when im testing the software but I need to find the sources which the event viewer uses to display the information.

For example a windows system update is easily found in the events viewer but where does the sources come from to display this information?

the same with system start up and shutdown.

Is there a link anyone could provide me or any other helpful information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application creates the event source, typically during installation (due to it requires privileges to create a source).